# Git commit policy that isolates changes to specific files as separate commits

Tags: git

I want to require SVGs to be committed separately from everything else to keep the diff output of everything else cleaner. For example, I want to disallow commits like this one:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   src/css/main.css
        modified:   src/images/example.svg
        modified:   src/index.html
```

Can this be done with a pre-commit hook? How would that be written?

Edit: I think `git ls-files -dmo` will be useful here, but I don't know how to write the script to parse its output.

Comment: Please don't append _solved_ to the title. Instead consider marking an answer as accepted. This will tell others that the question is now solved. Thank you.

Comment: UPDATE: My question was an instance of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) because my ultimate goal was "to keep the diff output of everything else cleaner." I was eventually persuaded that separating changes to `.svg` files into their own commits would violate the principle of [atomic commits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_commit#Revision_control).

Instead I am now using a `.gitattributes` file with the line `*.svg -diff` in it. This tells Git to treat `.svg` files as binary files, and so it will output "Binary files differ" as the diff message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can this be done with a pre-commit hook?

Yes.  (Note, however, that such hooks can be bypassed.)

> How would that be written?

Depends on what language you want to use to write it.

Shell scripts tend to be the simplest since you can just run Git tools directly.  Here, you might run `git diff-index --name-status` to compare the index (the proposed commit) to the current i.e. `HEAD` commit, then read through the files being added, modified, or deleted to see if any have names ending with `.svg`, and if any have names ending with anything else.  This lets you tweak the rules to allow *deleting* .svg files while making other changes.  Or, if file-status (added/deleted/modified) is not relevant, this is a bit simpler:

```
# straight from the sample pre-commit hook
if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1
then
        against=HEAD
else
        # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
        against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi

# create a temp file to hold diff output
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
trap "rm -f $tmpfile; exit" 0 1 2 3 15
git diff-index --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ADM $against > $tmpfile

# read the status and names from the temp file.
# we use a temp file simply because "| while read ..." runs
# a sub-shell which means that variable changes don't make
# it back to the parent shell.  there are other workarounds
# but this one is simple.
num_svg=0
num_nonsvg=0
while read name; do
    case "$name" in
    *.svg) num_svg=$((num_svg + 1));;
    *) num_nonsvg=$((num_nonsvg + 1));;
    esac
done < $tmpfile

# now disallow commit if there are mixed svg and non-svg files
if [ $num_svg -gt 0 -a $num_nonsvg -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "this commit affects both .svg files and non-svg files" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
# run any other checks here too
exit 0
```

(NB: this is entirely untested)

Comment: The above script will prevent the commit, If it has a svg file. But can we allow the commit without the svg file alone and add the svg file in a new  commit from the hook script itself? Note: this may not be what OP is asking. But I am looking for some solution like that

Comment: @karthick: it's theoretically possible to make a hook make its own separate commits, but it's a bad idea. Don't do it: write, instead, a script that makes the commits. The script can disable any hooks (using `--no-verify`) or set environment variables that control hooks (using any code you like at all).

Comment: Would `git ls-files -dmo --exclude-standard` produce the same results as your `git diff-index` command?

Comment: No, `git ls-files` reads the index ("what will be committed"), and can optionally compare it to the current *work-tree* (this is what `-d` and `-m` do), but does not compare it to the `HEAD` commit at all. Using `git diff-index --cached` compares `HEAD` ("what is committed now") vs the index.

Comment: Your caveat that it's entirely untested is appreciated, because it didn't work when I tried it. I added an `else` to the final test that prints the counter variables to see what's happening:
`echo "DEBUG: num_svg: $num_svg num_nonsvg: $num_nonsvg" 1>&2`

The output is always `DEBUG: num_svg: 0 num_nonsvg: 0`

Comment: Oh, duh, obvious bug, the loop needs its stdin redirected. Will fix.